# "bad file mode" error in qbasic

Tags: qbasic

I am just starting with file handling in qbasic. The program that I wrote always shows an error "bad file mode". Please help me!

```
OPEN "test.dat" FOR INPUT AS #1
CLS
INPUT "Enter username:"; a$
INPUT "Enter Password:"; b$
WRITE #1, a$, b$
CLOSE #1
END
```

Comment: Files in qbasic can be opened for input/output/append/binary/random.

Comment: This link describes file access in qb64 http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/OPEN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to `WRITE` output to a file then, logically, you might want to try this:

```
OPEN "test.dat" FOR OUTPUT AS #1
CLS
'etc
```

Answer (score 1):

A more descriptive sample of file access in Qbasic:

```
' input data and write to file:
OPEN "test.dat" FOR OUTPUT AS #1
INPUT "Enter Username:"; a$
INPUT "Enter Password:"; b$
WRITE #1, a$, b$
CLOSE #1
' open file for input and display data:
OPEN "test.dat" FOR INPUT AS #1
INPUT #1, a$, b$
PRINT "Username: "; a$
PRINT "Password: "; b$
CLOSE #1
END
```

Comment: Note how Write is paired with Input, whereas Print would be paired with Line Input for file access.